# Break on attaching of event in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I have a DOM node that is getting some click handlers attached to it. I want to break at the point it is being attached to the DOM node/element. There are multiple sources it could come from including possibly two versions of jQuery. Instead of finding the library code that is doing the attaching and setting a breakpoint there I would just like to right click on the element and say "break on event attachment". That direct functionality doesn't appear to exist yet. Is there an equivalent functionality in Chrome Dev Tools?

To clarify, I don't want to break on the event trigger but the event attach.

Comment: There could also be a delegated parent element that fires when the event "bubbles up" to it. i.e. `$(document).on('click', mySelector, function () {})`

Comment: Very good point, so I am thinking I would actually want that "break on event attachment" to include bubbling events.

Comment: I need to debug a code and find out where we add/remove an event to an element. Any update about this question?

Comment: I don't think I ever figured out how to do this, at least not natively with Chrome. We should definitely file this as a feature request with the Chromium project.